# Difference between express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/static')) and express.static(__dirname + '/static')

Tags: node.js, express, server, static, middleware

What's the difference between

```
express.static(__dirname + '/static')
```

and

```
express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/static'))
```

And which one i should use for serving the static files

Comment: They're pointing to different directories? Have you looked up what `path.join` does?

Comment: Made a mistake. Instead of public it had to be the static folder also

Comment: @jonrsharpe how are they pointing to different directories?

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED The post was edited since. there was a typo

Comment: Ah okay :) /length

Answer (score 1):

***`__dirname`*** is a global variable in Node.js which is:

> The directory name of the current module. [more read](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname)

i.e

```js
console.log(__dirname);
// Prints: /Users/mjr
```

you can reach it from anywhere in the app.

---

***`path.join()`*** is a function of nodes' [`Path` module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) which:

> joins all given path segments together using the platform-specific separator as a delimiter, then normalizes the resulting path.

i.e

```js
path.join('/foo', 'bar', 'baz/asdf', 'quux', '..');
// Returns: '/foo/bar/baz/asdf'
```

---

Both of your examples produce the same string (in this case!).
***BUT*** using `Path.join` will help you take care of constructing the path from different resources or other cases alike eliminating unnecessary delimiters.

i.e

```js
// with Path.join() => say if your platform specific separator is "/"
path.join('/a','b'); // will produce '/a/b'
path.join('\a','/b'); // will produce '/a/b'
path.join('a','\b'); // will produce 'a/b'
```

which also indicates that `express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/static'))`

can also be written like this:

`express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static'))`

---

Another example:

```js
express.static(`${__dirname}/${static_path}`)
```

This can produce problems if you aren't sure about the resource providing `static_path`, which can cause an invalid path string.